# Is Chewbacca's dialogue said on set, or dubbed in later?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, chewbacca

In the *Star Wars* films, the character Chewbacca doesn't speak Basic/English like the bulk of the cast.  Instead he speaks Shyriiwook, a language of growls/barks/etc.

Is someone (the actor, or a voice actor off-camera) saying his lines during filming?  Or is it recorded after filming and dubbed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like he spoke them in English on the set.

As further evidence, Peter Mayhew comments on how his spoken dialog on-set was largely improvised in [this Q&A](http://amatranscripts.com/ama/peter_mayhew_2013-09-01.html).

> **I can answer this. For A New Hope there were lines. In the Documentary that came with the original trilogy (sorry I forgot the name) there is a raw clip of the scene where Obi-wan leaves the crewin the controll room.
>   Chewie: That old mans crazy ! Han: You said it buddy.**
>
> Actually, I said: "The old man is mad" and I just made that up on set. Did that a lot back then. But hey, everybody knows what Chewie said....

Comment: I wonder if any of the actors knew what he would eventually sound like